# How to Filter Nested Collection within Dictionary using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my entity structure

```
Transaction Entity 

TransactionID, CompanyID  TransactionItems
  1             10           List<TransactionItems>
  2             10           List<TransactionItems>
  3             20           List<TransactionItems>

TransactionItems Entity

TransactionItemID TransactionID Value Postive Negative
1                  2            10    yes   
2                  2            20    yes
3                  2            30           yes   
4                  3            100          yes    
5                  3            200   yes   

I need to sum the values of Value based on positive or negative flag and then compute total like this

CompanyID Postive Negative
10          30     30
20          200    100
```

The function in Business layer is returning `Dictionary<int, List<Transaction>>` which is basically like this

```
Key         Value
CompanyID, List<Transaction>
```

So far i have only achieved this

```
 _Transaction.GetCompanyTransactions().
                Select(_Company => new
                {
                    Company = _Company.Key,
                    Positive = 
                    Negative =
                });
```

can any one help please

Comment: You basically need to `Sum` the `Value` where your flag is `Positive/Negative`.

Comment: As a side note, it should have probably been better to have only one `Positive` flag set to `True/False`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to sum the value field from the list :

```
_Transaction.GetCompanyTransactions()
    .Select(g => new { 
        CompanyId = g.Key, 
        Positive = g.Value.SelectMany(t => t.TransactionItems).Where(t => t.Positive).Sum(t => t.Value), 
        Negative = g.Value.SelectMany(t => t.TransactionItems).Where(t => t.Negative).Sum(t => t.Value)})
        });
```

Comment: `Where(t => t.Positive)` won't compile.

Comment: I think it should be `_Transaction.GetCompanyTransactions().Select(g => new { CompanyId = g.Key, Positive = g.Value.Select(s=> s.TransactionItems.Where(t => t.Positive).Sum(t => t.Value)), Negative = g.Value.Select(s => s.TransactionItems.Where(t => t.Negative).Sum(t => t.Value))});`

Comment: I've used a SelectMany instead of using two Sums like you did, though.

Comment: Yours looks better. Not having to sum twice is great.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `Sum` the values based on the `Positive/Negative` flag.

It is done in two steps: you need to `Sum` the inner items first, then `Sum` the inner sums.

```
_Transaction.GetCompanyTransactions()
            .Select(g => new
            {
                Company = g.Key,
                Positive = g.Value.Sum(t => t.TransactionItems.Where(x => x.Positive).Sum(x => x.Value)),
                Negative = g.Value.Sum(t => t.TransactionItems.Where(x => x.Negative).Sum(x => x.Value)),
            });
```